# OSX equivalent for ~/bin in Linux

Tags: terminal, bash

When using Ubuntu I can save shell scripts in ~/bin. To launch them I just type the name of the script in the Terminal. 
Is there an equivalent solution for OSX?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is none by default in OSX.  But you can make a ~/bin folder, then edit your ~/.profile and add

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Yourname/bin
```

(Yourname of course being replaced by your username).

or (edited later according to below comment)

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

Comment: You don't need to hardcode your username: `PATH=$PATH:~/bin`

Comment: In addition you can hide that folder in the finder by using the `SetFile` command. `SetFile -a V ~/bin`. I do that as a personal preference.

Comment: Glad to hear :-)

Comment: FYI, to create the '.bin' folder, use the "make directory" command: `mkdir bin` To list it: `ls -a` If you make a mistake, delete the folder by using "remove directory" command: `rmdir`